# Apktools on Mac

Tags: macos, apk, apktool

I went downloaded the Apktools from the website and got 2 files:  Apktool.txt and Apktool_2.2.2.  I renamed the Apktool_2.2.2 to Apktools.jar per the instructions.  I then went to terminal and this was what I did:

```
Last login: Fri Mar 17 12:08:55 on ttys000
Roberts-MBP:~ Robert$ cd documents
Roberts-MBP:documents Robert$ cd metronomeapp/apktool
Roberts-MBP:apktool Robert$ **java -jar apktool.jar**
Apktool v2.2.2 - a tool for reengineering Android apk files
with smali v2.1.3 and baksmali v2.1.3
Copyright 2014 Ryszard Wiśniewski <brut.alll@gmail.com>
Updated by Connor Tumbleson <connor.tumbleson@gmail.com>

usage: apktool
 -advance,--advanced   prints advance information.
 -version,--version    prints the version then exits
usage: apktool if|install-framework [options] <framework.apk>
 -p,--frame-path <dir>   Stores framework files into <dir>.
 -t,--tag <tag>          Tag frameworks using <tag>.
usage: apktool d[ecode] [options] <file_apk>
 -f,--force              Force delete destination directory.
 -o,--output <dir>       The name of folder that gets written. Default is apk.out
 -p,--frame-path <dir>   Uses framework files located in <dir>.
 -r,--no-res             Do not decode resources.
 -s,--no-src             Do not decode sources.
 -t,--frame-tag <tag>    Uses framework files tagged by <tag>.
usage: apktool b[uild] [options] <app_path>
 -f,--force-all          Skip changes detection and build all files.
 -o,--output <dir>       The name of apk that gets written. Default is dist/name.apk
 -p,--frame-path <dir>   Uses framework files located in <dir>.

For additional info, see: http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ 
For smali/baksmali info, see: https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali
Roberts-MBP:apktool Robert$ **./apktool d metronome.apk**
-bash: ./apktool: No such file or directory
Roberts-MBP:apktool Robert$ **apktool d metronome.apk**
-bash: apktool: command not found
Roberts-MBP:apktool Robert$
```

You can see in the bold what I entered.  On the 2nd and 3rd bold statements, I did it both ways because I found info that one of them works on windows and one on mac and since the mac one didn't work I wanted to try the windows one to see what it would say.  Both the files are in the same directory with the apk file (metronome.apk) Does anyone know why this isn't working and what I can do to resolve it?

Thanks.
Robert

Comment: Try `java -jar apktool.jar d metronome.apk`

Comment: Awesome!  This worked.

Comment: Mark answer if you wish. SO frowns upon comments that answer a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `java -jar apktool.jar d metronome.apk`

To elaborate, apktool.jar is not a command itself. It's a java Jar file that can be executed by the Java runtime.

Comment: Error: Unable to access jarfile apktool.jar

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, `apktool` can be easily installed using `brew`:

```bash
brew install apktool
```

Normally, once completed, `apktool` should be available for global straight-out usage in command line:

```bash
$ apktool
Apktool v2.7.0 - a tool for reengineering Android apk files
with smali v2.5.2-403e9037 and baksmali v2.5.2-403e9037
Copyright 2010 Ryszard Wiśniewski <brut.alll@gmail.com>
Copyright 2010 Connor Tumbleson <connor.tumbleson@gmail.com>


usage: apktool
 -advance,--advanced   prints advance information.
 -version,--version    prints the version then exits
usage: apktool if|install-framework [options] <framework.apk>
 -p,--frame-path <dir>   Stores framework files into <dir>.
 -t,--tag <tag>          Tag frameworks using <tag>.
usage: apktool d[ecode] [options] <file_apk>
 -f,--force              Force delete destination directory.
 -o,--output <dir>       The name of folder that gets written. Default is apk.out
 -p,--frame-path <dir>   Uses framework files located in <dir>.
 -r,--no-res             Do not decode resources.
 -s,--no-src             Do not decode sources.
 -t,--frame-tag <tag>    Uses framework files tagged by <tag>.
usage: apktool b[uild] [options] <app_path>
 -f,--force-all          Skip changes detection and build all files.
 -o,--output <dir>       The name of apk that gets written. Default is dist/name.apk
 -p,--frame-path <dir>   Uses framework files located in <dir>.

For additional info, see: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/
For smali/baksmali info, see: https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali
```